# "It is/was" in cleft sentences

Tags: past-tense, present-tense, cleft-constructions

I don't know which tense should be used in the following cleft sentence. In the non-clefted version, the past-tense is used, but in the clefted version, which tense is okay? If both are okay, what's the difference?

> It is/was no thanks to the Government that net assets did rise.

> Net assets did rise, no thanks to the Government.

Comment: I don't think it matters whether you use ***is*** or ***was*** (assuming that the rise in assets is reasonably current/recent, not part of a historical tract), but what looks completely wrong in both is ***did rise***, where I'd expect Simple Past ***rose***. Unless preceding text somehow implies that assets ***didn't*** rise (or feasibly, weren't ***expected*** to rise).

Comment: No difference at all between the two options?

Comment: If the context is one where it would be at least *possible* to say *Assets have risen* (as opposed to *Assets rose*, which would be the only acceptable verb form if that rise occurred some time ago), I'd say it makes absolutely no difference whether you use Past or Present for those first two words. Or you could just forget them and delete relativiser ***that*** as well - there's nothing syntactically wrong with *No thanks to the Government,  net assets rose* (though on purely stylistic grounds we'd normally put the adverbial element at the end, not the beginning, in this exact case).